# Extraction of information on merge mode in B-frames

Tags: hevc

I'm trying to extract the CU that used merge mode from the B frame after decoding using HM software. I understand that merge modes in B-frames include spatial prediction (one direction), temporal prediction (bi-directional), and combined bi-prediction.

I want detailed information on the merge mode in 4x4CU units. If a merge mode is used in the   target CU, I would like to know if it was a spatial or temporal prediction. If it were a spatial prediction, I would also like to know whether the prediction was from L0 or L1.

I have no experience in C++, but I hope to write the following code.

```
   string save = "**********";
    
   ofstream CU_merge;
   string CU_file_name = "cu_merge.txt";
   CU_merge.open(save + CU_file_name, std::ios_base::app);
    
   for (UInt ctuRsAddr = 0; ctuRsAddr < pcPic->getNumberOfCtusInFrame(); ctuRsAddr++)
         {
             TComDataCU* pCtu = pcPic->getCtu(ctuRsAddr);
             for (int i = 0; i < pCtu->getTotalNumPart(); i++)
             {
                 int zscan = g_auiRasterToZscan[i];
                 
                 if ((pcSlice->isInterB()) && (pCtu->isBipredRestriction(zscan) == false))
                 {
                     if (pCtu->getMergeFlag(zscan))
                     {
                         if (***)
                         {
                             //spatial prediction from L0
                             CU_merge << "S0";
                         }
                         else if (***)
                         {
                             //spatial prediction from L1
                             CU_merge << "S1";
                         }
                         else if (***)
                         {
                             //temporal prediction
                             CU_merge << "T"
                         }
                         
                         
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         CU_merge.close();
```